# Hostname consist of hyphen is giving IllegalArgumentException in android

Tags: android, url, hostname

I have an url like  `http://ashok-reddy:8080/hyd` which consists hyphen. While making Http Post request, I am getting IllegalArgumentException saying Host name may not be null . I have tried with replacing the hyphen with its hexadecimal value and also tried converting using URLEncoder/Uri.encode(). But nothing has been worked till now.

```
mHttpPost = new HttpPost("ashok-reddy:8080/hyd"); 
mEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
mEnvelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC; 
mStringEntity = new StringEntity(soapData, HTTP.UTF_8);         
mStringEntity.setContentType(mContext.getString(R.string.text_xml_content));     
mHttpPost.setEntity(mStringEntity); 
mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPost);
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Arindam

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a method  like URLEncoder, you should not pass the full URL, because it will escape even '//' symbols in url. For example, it will encode `://` into `%3A%2F%2F`

Pass to the function just the parameters list you need to encode to escape special characters.

EDIT:

As I can see you are using: `mHttpPost = new HttpPost("ashok-reddy:8080/hyd");`
instead of: `mHttpPost = new HttpPost("http;//ashok-reddy:8080/hyd");`

Comment: Thanks for reply..actually URLEncoder dosen't have any use in my case because the the problem is with -(hyphen)...

Comment: mHttpPost = new HttpPost("http://ashok-reddy:8080/hyd");
mEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
mEnvelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
mStringEntity = new StringEntity(soapData, HTTP.UTF_8);    mStringEntity.setContentType(mContext.getString(R.string.text_xml_content));
mHttpPost.setEntity(mStringEntity);
mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPost);

Comment: could you please suggest the way to use the URLEncoder with respect to above code...